# How to config VS 2012 IIS-express to listen requests from an OS installed on Microsoft Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, iis, hyper-v, visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure if I should ask this question here or not. However...
I'm using Windows 8 with VS 2012 and IIS-express 8 that is installed via VS. I mean when I was installing VS, it installed IIS and when I run a project, VS itself, runs IIS and when close VS, IIS will be closed too. In the other hand, I used Microsoft Hyper-V to install a Windows XP on my machine. My question is: how can I configure IIS to response to requests that come from my Windows XP? Is it possible? I mean when I run a web-project in VS and IIS got run, I want to be able to see my pages inside the XP too.

Comment: It sounds like you're running in an IIS test environment through Visual Studio.  When you execute your project and it opens locally in a browser, is there a port number at the end of the URL?  In a browser on your XP machine, try the IP of your VS/IIS computer with that port number.  There may be settings in the firewall, Web.config, or VS that you'll need to change to allow access from outside of localhost.  But someone here with more knowledge of VS/IIS will need to speak to that.

Comment: Yes there is port number. I tried it (from virtual machine and also from other computers on may LAN) but IIS did not response. I searched in firewall and VS. But I couldn't find any configuration section to solve this. It seems IIS itself needs to be configured, but while it's installed via VS (not a standalone app), I cannot find it's configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These stackoverflow questions address the same issue:

- [Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project/5438322#5438322)
- [Accessing IIS 7.5 Express from another machine on the intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924830/accessing-iis-7-5-express-from-another-machine-on-the-intranet)

Solutions from those cases:

- [Serving external traffic with WebMatrix Beta](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx)

Edit applicationhost.config file, your site bindings should like below;

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:your-machine-name" />
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry, it seems you are not familiar with VS and IIS. When I create a new web-project, VS creates a new virtual directory for it, and runs the project on IIS-express automatically. I'm using VS 2012 and IIS 8 express.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I am pretty familiar with VS having developed with it for 10+ years. However you are correct that I am not familiar with IIS-Express (just read this good [writeup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396569/Make-Web-Development-Easier-with-IIS-Express)). I did also find the solution to your problem and will update my answer.